# How to get Published Content by document type composition in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have the following Document Type composition:

- Page

  - HomePage
  - ContactPage
  - GeneralPage

**I would like to know how to get all Content by Document type composition**...

For example:

```
Umbraco.GetAllContentWhereDocumentTypeCompositionContainsType( "Page" )
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
@Model.AncestorOrSelf(1).DescendantsOrSelf("DocTypeAlias")
```